# Как можно заморозить основной метод пока не выполниться асинхронный?

Tags: c#, discord

Понимаю что заморозка основного метода на момент выполнения асинхронного выглядит немного бредовой, поскольку асинхронный метод и нужен для того чтоб выполняться независимо от основного, однако возникла такая надобность, Discord.NET требует чтоб бот находился внутри асинхронного метода.

представим такой вызов асинхронного метода:

```
static async Task<string> StartDiscordBot()
{
    string errorcode = await DiscordBOT.InitializeBot(Constants.DiscordBotToken);
    return errorcode;
}
```

и сам асинхронный метод:

```
static public async Task<string> InitializeBot(string token)
{
    try 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[DEBUG] Discord bot launched with token: {token}");
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ return ex.Message; }
}
```

мне нужно чтоб код замерз на моменте

```
string errorcode = await DiscordBOT.InitializeBot(Constants.DiscordBotToken);}
```

и не шёл дальше пока не получит return от `InitializeBot`, я пробовал использовать `.Wait()` вот так:

```
string errorcode = await DiscordBOT.InitializeBot(Constants.DiscordBotToken).Wait();
```

однако в таком случае получаю ошибку `CS4008    Cannot await 'void'`\

по просьбам из коментариев предоставляю минимальный самодостаточный пример:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string? errorcode = StartDiscordBot().ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(errorcode);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static async Task<string> StartDiscordBot()
    {
        string errorcode = await InitializeBot("TESTTOKEN");
        return errorcode;
    }
    static public async Task<string> InitializeBot(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[DEBUG] Discord bot launched with token: {token}");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return ex.Message; }
    }
}
```

мне нужно чтоб return в 'StartDiscordBot()' сработал только после того как 'InitializeBot()' завершиться, однако у меня return срабатывает моментально

Comment: Если в лоб, то убрать `await` и написать вместо Wait() `.Result`. Но это плохая практика. А как правильно решить и почему вам потребовалось такое замораживание - непонятно. Но в нормальной ситуации вы не должны хотеть использовать синхронное зависание потока вместо асинхронного ожидания. Так же использование `Wait()` или `Result` может вызвать дедлок - зависание насовсем. Используйте только `await`.

Comment: дело в том что программа в цикле просит ввод, и если ввод равен 1 то запускаеться бот, вызовом `StartDiscordBot()`, но из за асинхронности после вызова `InitializeBot` не дожидаясь return метод `StartDiscordBot()` заканчиваеться и все возвращаеться к циклу

Comment: await ожидает метод до того как он выполнится полностью. Я не понимаю сути проблемы.

Comment: вы уверены что await ожидает метод до того как он выполниться полностью? в моем случае InitializeBot идет выполняться, а метод StartDiscordBot заканчиваеться, и все возвращаеться к циклу из которого он был запущен

Comment: Конечно уверен. Асинхронный метод возвращает свой Task сразу, а await ждёт завершения этого таска. Если он дождался, то ждать больше уже нечего и ни Result не Wait вам не помогут. Там нет никакой магии внутри. Если поведение с await не подходит, надо решать изначальную проблему, а не искать костыли.

Comment: Перефорулируйте вопрос, методы InitializeBot и StartDiscordBot никак не связаны, возможно вы опечатались при вставке кода. Опишите изначальную задачу. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567

Comment: 1. Сделайте минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который воспроизведет эту проблему. Просто голый проект, с несколькими `Task` и их вызовом, этого будет достаточно для понимания того, что у вас не так, ибо [вот код](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x121LI), как видите, все "ждет" без каких либо проблем, ну а раз у вас нет, то скорей всего где-то `void` или нет вовсе `await`. 2. Уберите `static`, она вам тут вообще не нужна, особенно у класса "бота". 3. Для дискорда есть отличная библиотека, которая делает все то, что вы сейчас пытаетесь сами.

Comment: мне сделать голый проект с этой проблемой и просто кинуть весь проект через какой то обменник? или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ InitializeBot являеться статичным поскольку я вызываю этот метод из под другого класса и по другому он выдает ошибку  `CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DiscordBOT.InitializeBot(string)'`

Comment: Я от вас прошу **код**, который я или другой человек скопируем, запустим и скажем что вы делаете не так. Не куски кода, а полноценный, [минимальный, самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Что касается статики - ну так вы и не должны делать `DiscordBOT.InitializeBot()`, вы должны **создать экземпляр класса** и его использовать, условно `var bot = new DiscordBOT();` далее `bot.InitializeBot()` - это основы основ программирования, советую вам их осознать, пока не ушли далеко. Легкий путь (статика) не всегда верный, помните об этом!

Comment: Хорошо, я обновил вопрос

Comment: Так тут тоже `await` нужен, а `.ToString()` наоборот не нужен: `string? errorcode = StartDiscordBot().ToString();`! У вас просто возвращается `Task`, которую вы не ожидаете как положено, а печатаете её строковое представление. Кстати, что у вас на печать выводится в строке `Console.WriteLine(errorcode);` хотелось бы посмотреть, наверняка там есть толстый намёк на происходящее.

Comment: Где тут тоже нужен `await`? и что значит .ToString() не нужен? без него оно не хочет возвращать errorcode

Comment: Ну это же асинхронная функция, поэтому `string errorcode = await StartDiscordBot();`, точно так же, как при вызове `InitializeBot` у вас же в программе.

Comment: мне и не нужно делать `StartDiscordBot()` асирхнонным, он `async` только потому что по другому я получаю ошибку при вызове await InitalizeBot()

Comment: Без ожидания завершения задачи как вы собираетесь отловить момент, когда задача закончится? В том то и дело, что задача не закончилась, `return` ещё не сработал, а управление вы уже получили и получили результат в виде запущенной задачи. Чтобы получить результат работы задачи вам нужно этот результат ожидать через `await`. В общем, вы вообще неправильно диагностировали проблему. Вы просто не ожидаете задачу как положено, и она не завершается, как вы думаете, она продолжает работать. Вам нужно почитать какие-то материалы про асинхронность и задачи.

Comment: Спасибо, вызов `StartDiscordBot()` с использованием `await` решил мою проблему